# Paginator resets query as I change page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, filtering, paginator

I am developing an app in Django.

I have a template in which are displayed data from my model.

The template has a search bar and also a paginator.

The problem is that, when I run a query (let's say I search for the word "home"),
it shows the filtered results for page one, but as I click on my paginator to get to the next page, 
the query gets reset, and I get page 2 of unfiltered data (entire data).

So, how can I combine the filtering of results by search bar and paginator?

Here is my search bar code:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'glossario' %}">

            <input id="testo_slot_ricerca_semplice" type="text" placeholder="Ricerca terminologia..." name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}">  


            <!-- #cerca -->
            <button id="search_button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

            <!-- cancella query -->
            <button id="cancel_search_button" type="submit" onclick="Delete_simple_search()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>              


          </form>
```

Here is my paginator code:

```
<nav aria-label="...">
            <ul class="pagination">

                {% if all_entries.has_previous %}

                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a> 
                </li>

                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ all_entries.previous_page_number }}">{{ all_entries.previous_page_number }}</a>
                </li>

                {% else %}

                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">&laquo; first</a>  
                </li> 

                <!-- <li class="page-item disabled"></li>
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">previous</a>
                </li> -->

                {% endif %}



                <li class="page-item active">
                <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ all_entries.number }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>



                {% if all_entries.has_next %}

                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ all_entries.next_page_number }}">{{ all_entries.next_page_number }}</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }}">Last [ {{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }} ] &raquo;</a> 
                </li>

                {% else %}

                <!-- <li class="page-item disabled"></li>
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">next</a>
                </li> -->

                <li class="page-item disabled">
                   <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">Last [ {{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }} ] &raquo;</a>  
                </li> 

                {% endif %}

            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And here is my function in views.py populating the template:

```
def glossario(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q') 

    template = "glossario.html" 

    all_entries = glossary_entry.objects.all() 


    if query:

        query = request.GET.get('q') 
        selected_entries = glossary_entry.objects.filter(Q(Acronimo__icontains=query)|Q(Ambito_riferimento__icontains=query)|Q(Autore_definizione__icontains=query))


        # Pagination        
        paginator = Paginator(selected_entries, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        selected_entries = paginator.get_page(page)


        return render(request, template, {'all_entries':selected_entries})

    # se non è stata fatta nessuna query
    else:

        # Pagination
        paginator = Paginator(all_entries, 10) 
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        all_entries = paginator.get_page(page)

        return render(request, template, {'all_entries':all_entries})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

from views.py I am passing to my template a variable `query`, containing the `request.GET.get` of the terms submitted as I click "search" in the search bar (they are saved as `q` in the input of my search bar).
In my views.py, that variable is also defined before I get the input, so as the page loads the first time, its value is void.

To fix it, I implemented the following logic:

In the paginator,

- if my search bar submitted no query,
     I render the paginator as
  the one I swhowed in the question,
- otherwise,
     I concatenate the url to have both the search bar
  quesryset variable and the paginator page queryset variable.

See here:

in views.py:

```
def glossario(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q') 

    template = "glossario.html" 

    all_entries = glossary_entry.objects.all() 
    
    # if query has been submitted to search bar
    if query:
        
        query = request.GET.get('q') database
        selected_entries = glossary_entry.objects.filter(Q(Acronimo__icontains=query)|Q(Ambito_riferimento__icontains=query)|Q(Autore_definizione__icontains=query)|Q(Autore_documento_fonte__icontains=query)|Q(Data_inserimento_entry__icontains=query)|Q(Definizione__icontains=query)|Q(Host_documento_fonte__icontains=query)|Q(Id_statico_entry__icontains=query)|Q(Lemma__icontains=query)|Q(Posizione_definizione__icontains=query)|Q(Titolo_documento_fonte__icontains=query)|Q(Url_definizione__icontains=query)|Q(Url_documento_fonte__icontains=query))
        
        
        # Pagination        
        paginator = Paginator(selected_entries, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        selected_entries = paginator.get_page(page)
        
       
        return render(request, template, {'all_entries':selected_entries, 'query':query})

    # if query has NOT been submitted to search bar
    else:

        # Pagination
        paginator = Paginator(all_entries, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        all_entries = paginator.get_page(page)

        return render(request, template, {'all_entries':all_entries, 'query':query})
```

in template:

```
    <nav aria-label="...">
        <ul class="pagination">
            
        <!-- Se la q ha ricevuto un input = la search bar ha inserito input -->    
        {% if query %}
                            
            {% if all_entries.has_previous %}
            
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ query }}&page=1">&laquo; Prima pagina</a> 
                </li>
                    
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ all_entries.previous_page_number }}">{{ all_entries.previous_page_number }}</a>
                </li>

            {% else %}

                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">&laquo; Prima pagina</a>  
                </li> 
            
            <!-- <li class="page-item disabled"></li>
                <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">previous</a>
            </li> -->

            {% endif %}


            <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ all_entries.number }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>


            {% if all_entries.has_next %}
                
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ all_entries.next_page_number }}">{{ all_entries.next_page_number }}</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }}">Ultima pagina [ {{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }} ] &raquo;</a> 
                </li>

            {% else %}
                           
                <!-- <li class="page-item disabled"></li>
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">next</a>
                </li> -->

                <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">Ultima pagina [ {{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }} ] &raquo;</a>  
                </li> 
            
            {% endif %}

    <!-- Se la q è vuota = la search bar non ha inserito input -->
    {% else %}

    
        {% if all_entries.has_previous %}
                    
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page=1">&laquo; Prima pagina</a> 
            </li>
                
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ all_entries.previous_page_number }}">{{ all_entries.previous_page_number }}</a>
            </li>

        {% else %}

            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">&laquo; Prima pagina</a>  
            </li> 
        
        <!-- <li class="page-item disabled"></li>
            <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">previous</a>
        </li> -->

        {% endif %}


        <li class="page-item active">
        <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ all_entries.number }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>


        {% if all_entries.has_next %}
            
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ all_entries.next_page_number }}">{{ all_entries.next_page_number }}</a>
            </li>

            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }}">Ultima pagina [ {{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }} ] &raquo;</a> 
            </li>

        {% else %}
                    
            <!-- <li class="page-item disabled"></li>
                <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">next</a>
            </li> -->

            <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" class="page-item disabled">Ultima pagina [ {{ all_entries.paginator.num_pages }} ] &raquo;</a>  
            </li> 
        
        {% endif %}


    {% endif %}

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

The search bar code is left untouched.